# How appropriate it would be to give a gift card to an ex coworker who helped me with references?

Tags: references, relationships

One of my ex co workers recently helped me with glowing references, so I have been thinking to give him a gift card. Not a big one but just a small one. Would it be right to do that?

Comment: it sounds like a very nice thing to do.  I don't see a conflict of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would just thank him in an email and leave it that.  It's not that it's a "kick back", but if you're anything like me, you will work in more than one location during your career.  Do you give him a gift every time?  What about other references?  What if a future reference isn't quite so glowing (due to the passage of time)?  Do you withold a gift?  At what point could it all become unprofessional?

It's not a *big* can of worms, but it's still one I'd leave closed.  Thank him and move on :)

Comment: I like this answer and agree. The imagery of you withholding gifts because someone gave you a normal reference as opposed to a "glowing" reference cracks me up.

Answer (score 3):

If you're friendly with this person, I don't see an issue.

If you're not relatively close with this person, it could be mistaken for some kind of kick-back.

Comment: I worked quite closely with him since he was my manager, so I thought I should give something to him as a token of appreciation.

Comment: If he was someone you know well, then there is no harm.  I personally don't, because it gets expensive if I have to use them again in future as a reference! ;)

Comment: It's not a kick back if he wasn't expecting it in advance.